# Where is ʍǝɥʇɐɯ♦?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I haven't seen user [ʍǝɥʇɐɯ](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/1487/wehtam) on the site in some time. A look at his profile shows he hasn't logged into the site since November of last year. A quick look at [his Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600342/wehtam?tab=activity) shows that he has been active there.

This user left some good questions and answers. As has been [pointed out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3080941#3080941), this leaves a hole in the moderation team.

Is everything alright? Will this user be returning?

[image: Screen capture of mathew's user account, with "last seen" circled]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I exchanged a few emails with ʍǝɥʇɐɯ about two weeks ago. He'd mentioned that his Real Life demands had gotten quite intensive, but that he intended to return once those things had calmed down. He also mentioned that he had some great ideas for the site.

He's been using SO because it's relevant to his Real Life job, hence his activity there. He assured me he will be back as soon as the furor has died. :)

Comment: Ah, glad to hear it's something temporary. Any time frame for his return?

Comment: He didn't give me one, but I am sure he'll be back before Q1 is out. :D

Answer (score 8):

Sorry all! Bicycles.se is what I enjoy most, however, I live in a world where circumstances can change with those one loves and works with. Circumstance and commitments have got the better of me. Really. People do try to take away from you what you enjoy most and what you have the brightest and bestest dreams for.

I am not done yet, so, patience please, and I would like another crack at what I have planned to do with this site. Summer is not here yet, there is still a lot of Spring and I always had it in mind that Spring would be the time to get a wider community of people involved in the bike trade participating in bicycles.se.

Slacker I have been of late, not out of choice, but true none the less. I have some catching up to do and that is going to be starting today, if that is okay with everyone else. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Welcome back ʍǝɥʇɐɯ!